# Call method of one component in another component?

Tags: angular

I have two component that are not child-parent. My question is can i do something like this:

In component 2 do this:

```
constructor(private comp1:ComponentOne){
}

save(){
this.comp1.methodComponentOne();
}
```

Comment: component is also a `class` you can do with creating its `instance`

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly hack something to get something to work ... but it is *not* how components were meant to be used.

The purpose of a component is to provide the data (properties) and methods (functionality) needed by one particular view/UI. So there should never be code in one component that needs to be called by another component.

Instead, build a service. The purpose of a service is to provide code that can be accessed by any components.

I have an example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

This example shows how to share data, but you can share methods here as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `service` that can be '*injected*' in both components through their `constructor`. Then both components can interact with the service methods within themselves.

Answer (score 0):

This is the purpose of [services in Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). Also RXJS could assist with making some event hub between services.

Answer (score 0):

Methods that are likely to be used by different components should belong in a service, these can then be imported and injected into constructor and then method called as required.

```
import { CustomService } from '../services/custom.service';
.
.
 constructor(
private customService:CustomService,
) { }
.
.    
this.customService.someMethod();
```